# How do I return Http Response Content Length for ResponseEntity<List<Object>> without formatting issues or losing data from my response body?

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, httpresponse, response-entity

I'm trying to set the content length of my ResponseEntity<List> but the full list isn't returned in the response. I tried something like

```
    long contentLength = staticMethodGetsContentLength(List<Object> objectList);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Length", String.valueOf(contentLength));
    return Response.ok().headers(headers).body(objectList);
```

and then what is returned is a JSON list like

**[
{
"data": "data"**

without closing brackets or the full list of objects. Is there an easy fix for this or an alternative to what I'm doing?

Comment: Don't set it. The serializing stuff will do that if needed. Currently you prbably break it yourself by providingthe content-length (wrongly) which leads to the cut-off.

Comment: Do you have any links you could share that show this? M.Deinum

Comment: That show what?